# Oracle external table preprocessor feature

Tags: database, oracle

I have to read a file via external table but this file it's located into another directory inside the ACFS.
As first step I have to move the file
So, I decided to use the preprocessor feature running a script

Here's my table (premise: all permissions are set correctly etc)

`CREATE TABLE EXT_FILE
   (    "REC" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "VAL" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), 
    ...
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "ACFS_EXECDIR"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        PREPROCESSOR ACFS_EXECDIR:'preprocess.sh'
        FIELDS LDRTRIM 
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS 
        (
          "REC" (1:3) CHAR(3),
          "VAL" (4:7) CHAR(4),
          ...
        )
              )
      LOCATION
       ( 'file.ftp'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;`

this file is located into a folder and the script (preprocess.sh) into another
so I thought to proceed like this:
* move the file into the ACFS_EXECDIR directory,

so when executing the

> SELECT * FROM EXT_FILE

, the 'preprocess' feature would have executed the script which moves the file
into the default directory (**ACFS_EXECDIR**) then read it

**But it doesn't work..because it cannot find the file**

`KUP-04040: file file.ftp in ACFS_EXECDIR not found
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.`

So I've created a blank file just to **pass the exception** and it worked.
I thought the feature would have execute the script before anything else, then read it
of course the file is not there..

Another test I made was replacing the filename with the script's name to 'bypass' the exception again. It worked.

`LOCATION ( 'preprocess.sh')`

- Does the file have to be into the directory even before the execution
  of the preprocessor's script? Does it check if the file exists?
- Do I have to cat the file to view it inside the table? Again, I
  thought the external table would 'view' the file automatically after
  the execution of the script
- I cannot find the documentation of this feature for oracle
  **11g**, would you provide a link?

Thank you

SCRIPT:

```
    #!/bin/bash 
     #my dir
     DIR_FTP='...'
     DIR_ACFS='...' 
     /bin/mv $DIR_FTP/file.ftp $DIR_ACFS/file.ftp
     /bin/cat $DIR_ACFS/file.ftp # without cat cannot view the file
```

Comment: was your file located in a directory that on any of its levels there are no symbolic links? I had errors KUP-04027 and KUP-04017 "Oracle Directory object contains 1 symbolic links at path component /var/opt/XYZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SUTIL/et_params.htm#SUTIL1385) doesn't explicitly say so, but yes, the file has to already exist. The concept is to preprocess the specified file, not to perform an arbitrary action before the load starts.

The argument passed to the preprocessor script is the full operating system path to the file, so Oracle is constructing that from the directory object's path and the location file name - and presumably checking that it exists before doing anything else.

As you've seen, you can work around this by pointing the location to a dummy file, and have the preprocessor script do all the work - it doesn't even need to copy the file into the right directory, as long as it ends up cat'ing it. (Whether that's a good idea is another matter; make sure you've paid attention to the security warnings around this feature).

You do have to cat the file though:

> The preprocessor program converts the data to a record format supported by the access driver and then writes the converted record data to standard output (stdout), which the access driver reads as input.

One of the examples in the documentation is using `zcat` to uncompress a file - to standard output; it wouldn't make sense for it to end up looking at the original file name (which will still be the compressed file).

Comment: Thanks for reply
I was looking for the documentation of oracle 11g, anyway now I get it

Comment: That *is* the documentation for 11gR2. Though you seem to have to click on "what's new" on the left to see that; the same doc is also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1385). And [12c is here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-73A6DA8D-EA78-4B9B-BAB3-0C99BF190A50.htm#SUTIL1385).

Answer (score 0):

Quote from article:

> Preprocessor program must stream the input data directly to the external table—and not create another input file

[Preprocessor with external table](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21nanda-312277.html)