# Are Oracle External Tables per file

Tags: oracle

My question if I have in a dicrectory, for instance with  4 files with the same structure,  do I need to create one external table to each file or I can create the table in the top of the directory and have 1 external table to the 4 files .

Thanks

Comment: Will the same four files always be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [external tables concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-ACF1D3AA-1D61-4682-AEC5-42C944756E12) and [exmaples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-53C71354-FDC0-4CD7-BBF1-2B7327A1A245) show, you can specify multiple files in the locations clause:

```
...
LOCATION ('file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv')
...
```

If they are in different directories you can prefix each file name with the relevant directory name:

> - `LOCATION` — specifies the data files for the external table.
>
>   - For `ORACLE_LOADER` and `ORACLE_DATAPUMP`, the files are named in the form *`directory:file`*. The directory portion is optional. If it is missing, then the default directory is used as the directory for the file. If you are using the `ORACLE_LOADER` access driver, then you can use wildcards in the file name: an asterisk (*) signifies multiple characters, a question mark (?) signifies a single character.

... but that doesn't seem to be relevant to your situation.

The number and names of the files are fixed though, unless you use wildcards.

If you will always have the same number of files but different names you could potentially add a preprocess clause to rename other files to match those expected names; or probably more practically, just have a single dummy expected name and [use a preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521084/266304) to combine all the files into one standard output stream that is actually used by the access driver.

Comment: Thanks a LOT Alex

Comment: Alex just a question, if I have more than one directory it would be somethjing like LOCATION ('directory1.file1.csv', 'directory1.file2.csv', directory1.'file3.csv', 'directory1.file4.csv',directory2.file1.csv', 'directory2.file2.csv', directory2.'file3.csv', 'directory2.file4.csv')

Comment: @LaerteJunior - yes, that's what the documentation I linked to shows. I've included the relevant part as a quote too now.

Comment: I have another question on extenral tables but I will create a new question . Thanks a lot