# sql loader without using database password

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a CSV file which I need to upload into a database table. I have written an SQL loader for the same and am able to upload the csv in the table, but the  problem I am facing is that I am having to  hard code the password in the loader script itself.
The entire thing is supposed to be automated, where user will be uploading file to a specific folder on the server. For this we will be using a shell script which will be fetching the file. Then using the SQL loader it will upload the values into the table.

Is there any way to use the SQL loader without providing the password?

Comment: Why can't the user running the shell script provide the password at runtime? As the file is on the server you could possibly use an external table as a stage instead, but then you'd need to invoke something in the DB to copy data from that to the real table, which might just shift the question to a SQL\*Plus password, unless it can be scheduled - it doesn't sound like it can be?

Comment: @AlexPoole Hi Alex, we will be using a cron to schedule the script so there will be no user intervention, will think over the option of external table if that is possible to implement, Thanks

Comment: Then you could possibly use a job scheduled in the DB instead of via cron, with a preprocessor step to copy the file to the right place (or [fake it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521084/266304)).

Answer (score 3):

Two options I can think of.

The **first** one is to create a *parameter file* that contains values of all parameters you need. For example (my_parfile.par):

```
userid=scott/tiger
control=my_loader.ctl
log=my_loader.log
```

and you'd run SQL*Loader as

```
sqlldr parfile=my_parfile.par
```

Obviously, it does contain username/password, but you don't see it in the command line.

**Alternatively**, if you use only a slash `/` as `USERID` value, then it defaults to your operating system login. This might be what you're looking for. Personally, I've never used it so I can't provide an example and claim *it'll work* as I simply don't know. Google probably does.

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1** Oracle Server 9.2.0.8 Linux,  Client Windows 9.2.0.1

to establish remote OS authentication you need

1 set in pfile or spfile   `REMOTE_OS_AUTHENT=TRUE`

2 Check `OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX`

```
select name, value from v$parameter  where name='os_authent_prefix';
    NAME                         VALUE                                                                                                
------------------- ------------------------------------------------ 
os_authent_prefix              ops$
```

3 Create user

```
CREATE USER OPS$DEMINDV IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY
DEFAULT TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_DEMINDV
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON TABLESPACE_DEMINDV
PROFILE DEFAULT
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

4 check oracle client sqlnet.ora  `$ORACLE_HOME\network\admin\sqlnet.ora`

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

5 Test connection

```
C:\Program Files\Far Manager>sqlplus /@test-ecdu

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Jun 22 12:46:40 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

connected> show user
USER is "OPS$DEMINDV"
connected>
```

6 Run sqlldr.exe and load data

```
C:\oracle\ora92\rdbms\demo>sqlldr.exe /@test-ecdu control=ulcase2.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Jun 22 12:19:39 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 7

C:\oracle\ora92\rdbms\demo>
```

**Example 2** 
Oracle Server 9.2.0.8 Linux and local user Linux OS `test`

Create oracle user

```
CREATE USER OPS$TEST IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY
    DEFAULT TABLESPACE TABLESPACE_DEMINDV
    TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
    QUOTA UNLIMITED ON TABLESPACE_DEMINDV
    PROFILE DEFAULT
    ACCOUNT UNLOCK
/
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO OPS$TEST
/
ALTER USER OPS$TEST DEFAULT ROLE "RESOURCE"
/
```

Test connection

```
[test@test-ecdu bin]$ sqlplus /

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production on Fri Jun 22 13:10:55 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production

SQL> show user
USER is "OPS$TEST"
SQL>
```

Run sqlldr and load data

```
[test@test-ecdu demo]$ sqlldr / control=ulcase2.ctl log=/home/test/ulcase2.log

SQL*Loader: Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production on Fri Jun 22 13:20:21 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 7
[test@test-ecdu demo]$
```